# How to get the attribute Value of an xml tag created with namespace?

Tags: javascript, xml

```
    <root xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'  xmlns:element='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
<element:group>
<element:content url='https://myrequiredurl.com' otherattr='360' otherattr='640' otherattr='somthng' medium='smtng'/>
<element:content url='https://myrequiredurl.com'  otherattr='720'  otherattr='1280'  otherattr='smtng' medium='smtng'/>
<element:content url='https://myrequiredurl.com'  otherattr='1080'  otherattr='1920'  otherattr='smtng' medium='smtng'/>
</element:group>
</root>
```

Above is my xml doc i need to get the 'url' attribute from first `'<element:content/>'` tag i tried the ways mentioned in w3schools.com but i had

no luck some help is much appreciated i need to access it using javascript sorry for bad question framing

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this using dom manupulation.

HTML:

```
<p id="show"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
  var urlList = [];
  var txt = "<root xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:element='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>" +
    "<element:group>" +
    "<element:content url='https://1myrequiredurl.com' otherattr='somthng' medium='smtng'> </element:content>" +
    "<element:content url='https://2myrequiredurl.com' otherattr='smtng' medium='smtng'> </element:content>" +
    "<element:content url='https://3myrequiredurl.com' otherattr='smtng' medium='smtng'> </element:content>" +
    "</element:group>" +
    "</root>";
  if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
  }
  else // For Internet Explorer
  {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
  }

  var group = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("root")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes;

  for (var content in group) {
    if (!isNaN(content)) {
      var url = group[content].getAttribute("url")
      urlList.push(url);
    }
  }

 document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = urlList.join("</br>");
```

P.S: "You cannot add multiple attributes with the same name".

you can find the solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/vineetsagar7/3od130pd/2/

Comment: Thank you I was just trying to mention that there are some other attributes  too with "otherattr" anyway thank you for the solution